# How can I disable parameter auto-completion when selecting a suggested function in VS Code with the clangd extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-completion, clangd

When typing the prefix of a function name in VS Code, the IDE will provide suggestions to choose from. When using [the clangd extension](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd), if the suggestion is a function and the user selects it using the Tab key, VS Code will automatically complete the parameter list and enter a strange editing mode. However, sometimes when the user wants to use the function as a function pointer, this feature can be annoying.

[This is the suggestions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhtEP.png) 
[After selecting, the content within the red box will be automatically completed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe1yc.png)

I have tried to disable this feature in both VS Code settings (such as disabling Inlay hints, etc.) and clangd settings(not been able to find any relevant options in the [official documentation](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html) for clangd).

If I set `editor.suggest.showFunctions` to `false` in VS Code, there will be no more suggested functions, which is not what I want.

Comment: is the "strange editing mode" you're referring to [snippet mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)? Also loosely related: https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/issues/420

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
{
    "clangd.arguments": [
        "--function-arg-placeholders=0"
    ],
}
```

This information provided courtesy of [Disable function/method arugment insertion.!?
#92](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/issues/92).

For your reference / learning purposes, I found that issue ticket by searching ["`is:issue function argument` "](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/issues?q=is%3Aissue+function+argument) in [the GitHub issues page for the VS Code clangd extension](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/issues).

---

Old answer before more clarification was added:

Is this not just a case of having to put `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)?

If you want this setting to only apply to C++ files, then you can wrap the setting in `[cpp]: { ... }`.

Also related if you're using the [vscode-cpptools](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) extension: `C_Cpp.autocompleteAddParentheses` (default value is `false`).

The clangd extension configuration contributions can be found [here](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/blob/master/package.json), but I think all you need is `editor.parameterHints.enabled`.