# VSCode disable suggestion of variables after each comma

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode (1.85.0) to write my R markdown scripts. I really like the features it offers, but one thing which bugs me is that when I am inside of a function, like `dplyr::select()` and I am listing variables I want to select, VSCode suggests just random variables that I have defined in my script before after each ",". I have attached an image below:

[image]

In this case, `chrom` is not a column name that exists in the `gene_df`, it is just some variable I defined before. It is really annoying, because if I just quickly press enter to jump to the new line, it instead selects the `chrom` text...

I would really appreciate if anyone knows how to turn off this feature!

Cheers!

Comment: does disabling quick suggestions help? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77649862/11107541

Comment: For me, this disables basically all suggestions that VSCode offers to me, not just when I am inside of a function.

Comment: loosely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933450/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76004921/11107541